# Form with POST method returns $_REQUEST but $_POST is empty

Tags: php, forms, post

Using PHP7.x, I have a simple form

```
<form method='post' action=''>
<input type='text' name ='yourname'>
<input type='submit' name = 'submitted' value = 'here'>
</form>
```

The submit button works fine. Looking at the POST with developer tools, I see the values of the input fields submitted. So the POST parameters in the Developer tools window show the entered value.

But if my processing page (the 'action' page) contains this code

```
echo $_POST['yourname'];
```

The output is null.  This statement
`echo $_REQUEST['yourname']` shows the entered value.

Why doesn't `$_POST['yourname']` show a value?

And, I sanitize all form data with this command

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

I can change my code to use the `$_REQUEST['yourname']`, but why doesn't `$_POST['yourname']` show data? And, will my `filter_input_array()` 'clean' the resultant `$_REQUEST` values?

**Added**
Made the correction to the code (I put the 'action' in the wrong statement in my sample code; the code was not the actual used. Actual code had the 'action' parameter in the proper location. Sample code was a generic sample, as I have seen this problem in many areas of code using 'forms'.

But don't understand the 'close'. This is a programming area (to my understanding), and this is a programming question: "Why does a POST not populate the $_POST array on submit".

And, the secondary question "Does the filter_input_array 'clean' the variables placed in $_REQUEST ?" was not answered. (Maybe that should have been a separate question.)

But disappointed and unclear as to why this is not an appropriate question for this stack. (And yes, I read the 'rules'.)

Comment: Is `$_GET['yourname']` set? `$_REQUEST` normally combines both `$_POST` and `$_GET`.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the provided code.

Comment: `action` is an attribute of `form` not `input`.

Comment: I frankly disagree with the decision to close this as off-topic.  This is a specific programming problem, and is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development.  Although the nature of the problem makes it non-reproducible in a properly set up php config, does that mean the question is off topic?  Isn't the point of SO to help programmers fix problems?  Meanwhile I see mindlessly stupid questions getting voted up while real issues like this get closed... SMH...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some further testing on this, trying to simplify the code and duplicate the problem. The code is on a site that has various 'includes'. So I took my simple code (just a form and then `print_r` of the $_GET/POST/REQUESTs) to help duplicate the problem.

My `includes` include these statements to sanitize all inputs:

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Looks OK, doesn't it? Standard sanitize of the `$_GET` and `$_POST` variables. Nothing to see here. Move along.

**But look more closely.** I've used these statements in my code lots of times. Kept going.  But it should be this:

```
$_POST = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$_GET = filter_input_array(INPUT_GET, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
```

Note that the first block is filtering the GET into POST, and the POST into GET. *Dyslexic code!*

I call that a "SAF" error - "Smack Against Forehead". Or "LCG" - "Look Closely, Grasshopper".

`<sigh>`  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are still unable to access `$_POST` variables after correcting the html, there is another possible cause.

#### variables_order directive

There is a directive in the php.ini configuration file that determines which of the superglobal variables are used, and in what order.

From the manual:

> variables_order string
>
> Sets the order of the EGPCS (Environment, Get, Post, Cookie, and Server) variable parsing. For example, if variables_order is set to "SP" then PHP will create the superglobals $_SERVER and $_POST, **but not create** $_ENV, $_GET, and $_COOKIE. Setting to "" means no superglobals will be set.

#### request_order directive

Furthermore, `$_REQUEST` has its own directive, which appears to supercede the variables_order directive:

> request_order string
>
> This directive describes the order in which PHP registers GET, POST and Cookie variables into the _REQUEST array. Registration is done from left to right, newer values override older values.
> **If this directive is not set**, variables_order is used for $_REQUEST contents.

**Finding php.ini**

From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php)

```
<?php
$inipath = php_ini_loaded_file();

if ($inipath) {
    echo 'Loaded php.ini: ' . $inipath;
} else {
    echo 'A php.ini file is not loaded';
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer to what I think was a valid question for this stack. I looked at those variables in the php.ini file, and they were not set, so the defaults were used. I'll need to dig into the manual for more info on those directives, and how they are processed. Thanks.

Comment: I looked at the PHP settings in that system. The 'request_order' is set to "GP". The 'variables_order' is set to "GCPS". So don't think those are the cause. I seem to recall $_POST containing variables in PHP v5.3. But in PHP 7.3 , $_POST is empty, and all form variables are shown in $_REQUEST. Which is puzzling to me (as many things are).

Comment: You certainly should have $_POST variables; there’s got to be something wonky with your setup. You might try setting it to GPCS, although I don’t think that’ll make a difference. Also, make sure you’re checking the right ini file; the CLI has one too.

Comment: Found the problem. See my 'checked' answer. Thanks.

Comment: @RickHellewell *facepalm* ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

First off,

The HTML looks a little off..

1. The action attribute is not a valid attribute for input.
2. The submit button has spaces in them
3. There is not action declared on the form, most browsers will post it to the referring page but not all.

If i fix up the code like this i have good output:

```
<?php // this file is test.php
    if (sizeof($_POST))
      var_dump($_POST);
?>
   <form method='post' action='test.php'>
   <input type='text' name ='yourname'>
   <input type='submit' name='submitted' value='here'>
   </form>
```

I get the expected response:

`array(2) { ["yourname"]=> string(4) "test" ["submitted"]=> string(4) "here" }`

Comment: This is all wrong. `action` is optional on the form, **every** browser will handle that just fine. The `action` on the input will be ignored by virtually every browser, and spaces in HTML are perfectly valid. None of the things you point out here can possibly be responsible for the behavior seen by OP. If you're getting the expected results with your markup, it's because you failed to first reproduce the problem using OP's markup.

Comment: I fixed the 'action' being in the wrong spot. I blame my keyboard. But even when corrected, the $_POST varaibles do not contain the form values; the form values are in the $_REQUEST variables. I think it is a setting between various versions of PHP (current is 7.3, but I recall $_POST working in 5.3).

Comment: Found the problem. See my 'checked' answer. Thanks.